# how to migrate virtual to physical disk

Tags: linux, virtualbox, virtual-machine, dmg-image, vdi

My plan is to migrate open virtual format(.vmdk,.raw,.dmg,.vdi) to physical partition. I tried to restore virtual file to USB using powerISO but didn't boot.
I've .dmg and vmdk file, how to migrate virtual to HDD?

Comment: On what Mac? & do you have a spare you could do the cloning with?

Comment: I've Windows and ubuntu, in which OS(.dmg and .vmdk file) and I've spare hdd and usb drive

Comment: Then I'm afraid your question is off-topic for Stack Exchange. The use of OSX on non-Apple hardware is a legal grey area and as a result "Hackintosh" questions have been deemed [off-topic](http://meta.superuser.com/questions/1471/are-hackintosh-questions-allowed).

Comment: @Tetsujin Now I've changed the question, How to convert open virtual format to physical ?

Comment: Well, on a Mac you just clone it to an HD & boot from it - but that's not going to work for anything else.

Comment: @Tetsujin that way is working file using virtual box but I need to boot from physical disk

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/38852/discussion-between-ravi-g-and-tetsujin).

Comment: Not sure what therse are, but is [`virt-v2v`](http://libguestfs.org/virt-v2v.1.html) not working for them? (Should support VMware ESXi, Xen, Hyper-V)

Comment: This is not a Question and Answer forum, What has your research effort shown using Google? Questions on SU are expected to show some research effort on your part and should be included in your Question.